# SQL Server 2008: Run Xquery from values in database on values in database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, xquery

I have a table storing multiple values that I want to use in an Xquery to find data in another table matching the results. The Xquery strings are built to return either a true or false when evaluated using `xmlData.Exists(value)`. Here is what I have so far:

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [XquerySearch] 
@xquery nvarchar(4000)    

DECLARE 
    @sqlcmd NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @SafeXquery NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @SafeXquery = REPLACE(@xquery, '''', '''''')

SET @sqlcmd = N'SELECT d.[guid], p.pGuid, 
    FROM Data AS d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PDataLink as p on d.[guid] = p.pGuid
    WHERE d.xmlData.exist(''' + @SafeXquery + ''') = 1';
exec (@sqlcmd)
```

Above is the only way  I've found to be able to run an xquery using a dynamic value as the search parameter (not the actual field being searched).

OK, so now assuming I have another stored procedure called `RunQuery`, which is building a result set searching other parameters, such as creationDate. I can't figure out how to use the `XquerySearch` stored procedure above to provide a final result set that meets my other criteria and Xquery criteria.

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [RunQuery] 
@queryid int

DECLARE @ideaTestingTable table ( pGuid uniqueidentifier)
~*****~

SELECT Distinct p.guid
FROM Parent p
LEFT OUTER JOIN PDataLink pdl ON p.[guid] = pdl.pGuid
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data d ON pdl.dataGuid = d.[guid]
CROSS JOIN QueryParams q
WHERE q.id = @queryid
AND ~My other search parameters are true~
AND ~*****~
```

~***********~ = How can I either build up a temp table that with a list of `pGuid` that have matching `d.xmlData` under them (possibly calling the XquerySearch stored procedure) to then add into the `where` at the bottom `AND p.[guid] IN @ideaTestingTable` or some way to run the xquery directly from the where clause.

Comment: As an ugly solution, I would have a function, XQuerySearchGenerateSql, return the SQL Code of the select (XquerySearch would just exec this result). Then in RunQuery, I would build a big select through string concatenation, including the code provided by XQuerySearchGenerateSql as a subquery `'...and p.guid in ('+XQuerySearchGenerateSql(@XpathQuery)+')' (I don't have the beautyful solution ;-)

Comment: I might end up having to try something like that, but I'm really really hoping there is a solution that doesn't involve more string concatenation

Comment: Another option might be to have your procedure create a table-valued function or view, then use this function/view in runQuery, then destroy the function/view afterwards (if it would work, that means less string concatenation )

Comment: @jbl I ended up going with string concatenation as it proved fastest in the end. If you put that as an answer I will mark it as the answer otherwise I will just answer it for sake of having an answer.

Comment: Your answer would be way better than any I would post. Thx for the offer and for the follow-up anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is probably the least appealing of the solutions, after trying many possibilities, building the SQL query through string concatenation proved to be the fastest method.

So, in the places that I am doing Xquery searches, I do string concatenation for the searches. This allows the Xquery to be run with dynamic queries but also allows the Xquery to be run only on the rows that have already passed the other parameters instead of like the first Stored Procedure in the question which scanned the entire `Data` table.